# Replacing a DataReader with a DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, datatable, sqlcommand

I'm adapting some code that someone else wrote and need to return a DataTable for time's sake.

I have code like this:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
      //add parameters and their values

      using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
      {
          return dr;
      }
```

But what's the best way to return a datatable?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use the [DataTable.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to fill your table with values from the SqlDataReader:

```
using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    var tb = new DataTable();
    tb.Load(dr);
    return tb;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

By using a DBDataAdapter

excerpt from ms documentation

```
// Create the DbDataAdapter.
DbDataAdapter adapter = new DbDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = command;

// Fill the DataTable.
DataTable table = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(table);
```

Comment: It says that I cannot create an instance of the abstract class