# SqlCommand execute with multi result

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

When I execute 3 line script(or more) (Example: I UPDATE, II DELETE, III SELECT), SSMS gives me 3 Message(s) and 1 Result(s):

1. I UPDATE -> x row(s) affected
2. II DELETE-> x row(s) affected
3. III SELECT -> x row(s) affected
4. III SELECT -> grid view

How can I make it my own? using C#.

I'm creating:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("blabla");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("my script", cn);
```

now I need execute and get all type of result

1. row(s) affected
2. row(s) affected
3. DataTable (or DataSet)

Comment: Why do you need to run them as 1 script?  Do you just need the number of rows affected for the `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and` DELETE`?

Comment: Why run them all in the same statement? Use a SqlTransaction, commit the transaction after the last statement executes.

Comment: I need all in one, because that not me who generating scripts, is there any way to do it like Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you subscribe to the [`StatementCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.statementcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event you can get the rowcounts you want.

```
var rowCounts = new List<int>();
var resultSets = new List<DataTable>();

using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(myScript, cn))
{
    cmd.StatementCompleted += (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        rowCounts.Add(eventArgs.RecordCount);
    };
    cn.Open();

    using (var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        do
        {
            var table = new DataTable();
            table.Load(rd);
            resultSets.Add(table);
        } while (rd.NextResult());
    }
}

//rowCounts now holds all of the reported rowcounts
//resultSets now holds all of the result sets returned.
```

Important note, if someone did `SET NOCOUNT ON` in their script the event `StatementCompleted` will not fire, to get rowcounts in that situation you have to use `@@rowcount` in the script and return it explicitly as a result set in a `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume its so that the whole thing fails or succeeds right? Why not just use the same connection and a transaction and then commit the transaction at the end. That is what transactions are there for. See the [SqlTransaction documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction(v=vs.110).aspx) for more examples and detail.

```
private static void Demo1()
{
    SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection("connstringhere");
    SqlTransaction transaction;

    db.Open();
    transaction = db.BeginTransaction();
    try
    {
        var updateResultNums = new SqlCommand("UPDATE", db, transaction).ExecuteNonQuery();
        var deleteResultNums = new SqlCommand("DELETE", db, transaction).ExecuteNonQuery();
        var reader = new SqlCommand("SELECT", db, transaction).ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // read
            // alternatively see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13870892/1260204 if you really want a data table from the SqlCommand
        }
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlError)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        // do something to handle error
    }
    finally
    {
        db.Close(); //close connection
        db.Dispose(); //dispose connection
        transaction.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using catch and finally blocks you really should just use `using` statements and wrap the connection and transaction in them.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - I disagree. `using` translates to a `try/finally` block in IL so, IMO, its whatever up to someone's personal preference as it makes no difference in the resulting IL code. I like `using` blocks if there is only 1 `IDisposable` object I am dealing with. If there are many then I hate the look of nesting, same is for if there needs to be a catch block. To me the code is more readable with one `try/catch/finally` where all disposables are dealt with in the `finally`.

Comment: You don't need to nest them, look at the answer i posted them for a example of using blocks without the indent nesting. Also, you really should dispose in the oppisate order of creation, `transaction` should be disposed before `db`. In this case it does not matter (I think) but other types might not be as forgiving if you dispose of them out of order.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - its a good answer as far as it address the OPs concerns. This is still nesting though isn't it and nesting is not the same as indenting. Again, its your preference to use multiple using blocks, mine is to avoid it.