# How to use a DateTimePicker and format DateTime to create this SQL SELECT query for Access?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, select, datetimepicker

When I run this code, I get table columns without data.

Date is designed as Short text in Ms Access database.

```
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
try
{
    String date = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();

    cmd.Connection = connection;
    String query = "SELECT * from Events where DOB ='"+date+"'";

    cmd.CommandText = query;
    Console.WriteLine("" + query);
  
    OleDbDataAdapter oa = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    oa.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

How to solve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Data Connections Best Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552829/c-sharp-data-connections-best-practice)

Comment: [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Can you check in your debugger what is value  String date =dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();

Comment: What is the format of the value date passed to the query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turning a SqlCommand with parameters into a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870843/turning-a-sqlcommand-with-parameters-into-a-datatable)

Comment: I usually use typed DataSet, but I see the query is never executed in the provided code, so should it be? Or the Fill method do that?

Comment: The Fill method does that. If I hard code a DOB value like    String query = "SELECT * from Events where DOB =' #01/24/2020"; it displays on the table but using dateTimePicker, I get an empty table

Comment: @arreytabeebob Ok, thanks. So use [SQL parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter) as [explained](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types) in the link above about [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection), with named parameters else positional parameter `(?)` if the ADO.NET provider, the ODBC driver or the DB don't support. You also need to respect DB date/time format (I don't know for Access right now) if not custom string.

Answer (score 0):

Force a *format* on the date *value*:

```
DateTime date = dateTimePicker1.Value;

String query = "SELECT * from Events where DOB = #" + date.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#";
```

Comment: [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: @OlivierRogier: Nothing to "inject" here; a DatePicker can only return a date value.

Comment: @.Gustav Even if you are sure that the `ToString` formatting parameter as well as the query cannot be badly written to be SQL infected, and that no other coder can modify this line of code, or that the type in the database will never be changed, this is a very bad habit of not getting into the good habit of using SQL parameters, I think, because it quickly becomes a bad habit, and it will be hard to undo that.

Comment: @OlivierRogier: Of course, parameter usage is optimum, but if you can't write a correct hard-coded format string, you are facing major challenges.

Comment: Thanks @Gustav that was very helpful. I'm able to have data on all columns.